# what is the problem with j1000 drive?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, industrial-engineering, electronics

I have problem in the drive-J1000, not running , shows F 9.50 on display , just twinkling here is a video

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JasqdFWffqOWf1wKko-XR6xYs1OKAzdu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So what does a search through the documentation give for "F9.50"?

Comment: Didn't find it in the documentation

Comment: Fault codes are usually explained somewhere...